# What does d mean in svg path?

Tags: html, svg

```
<svg height="210" width="400">
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>
```

Does d stand for something in particular? I couldn't find anything via Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `d` refers to the `<path>` data. ([mdn link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d))
- `M` tells the canvas to put the pen down at a specific location. It doesn't draw to that point from wherever it was previously.
- `L` tells the canvas to draw a line from wherever it was last to the given coordinate.
- `Z` tells the canvas to stop drawing (pick the pen up).

I found [this overview](https://web.archive.org/web/20140419132513/https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-basic-shapes-and-d3js) from Dashing d3js on SVGs helpful.

Comment: d3 blog link is broken. Do you know the latest link if possible?

Comment: @theprogrammer fixed

Answer (score 19):

`d` is Path **Data**. The definition of the outline of a shape.

Reference : http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData

Comment: Been using SVGs for years, and just came here to find out what it stood for, because I was curious. I guess _data_ is it, though I've also seen people call it _description_ and _definition_.